# vim plugin for searching legal unbalanced brackets across preprocessor #if, #else, #endif in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, vim

In Vim, '%' can be used to search for matching brackets.  However, in editing C/C++ code like this:

```
function f()
{
    if (a) {
        A();
#ifdef FOO
    } else if (foo_0) {
        foo(0);
    }
#else
    } else {
        bar();
        foo(1);
    }
#endif
}
```

That is, a legal C/C++ code with unbalanced brackets (4 opening brackets but 5 closing brackets).  Vim command '%' won't even match the starting/ending brackets of function `f()`.

Is there any plug-in or any way to match these unbalanced brackets across preprocessor conditional directives?

Comment: I would say that this is a good example of why **not** to use the style of having the closing `}` on the same line as the `else [if] {` block! Put the closing brace on a line by itself and you won't have the problem.

Comment: The problem is not my code, but others', especially from open source projects.

Comment: @RobinHsu Do you have a real life example? I feel that this is borderline abuse of the preprocessor and would warrant a commit to fix the code not to do this. About any decent programming editor will match braces and I doubt any of them will try to interpret `#if` blocks to see if they balance... There are at least two ways to fix this code (move the `}` before the `else`s above the `#if`, or move the final `}` below the `#endif`), so I really can't see a real life example that couldn't be restated in a way that's friendly to brace matching in editors.

Comment: Yes, it's a real life problem, and it could be restated.  The problem is, who wants to change just a few lines, submit a small patch, and go through the lengthy open-source code review to fix it?    I think the best way is to have code-style checker to do the job, and discourage the code submission in the first place.

Comment: The layout is typical of languages like TCL and AWK which result in syntax errors unless the braces are coded like that.  The problem is when switching from C and vice-versa.  To avoid syntax errors in TCL, the easiest way is to use similar syntax.